# Create a customer converter and validator using ATTRS

Tags: python, python-attrs

I am trying to learn attrs and I have two questions.  Please note that I am using the ATTRS library, not ATTR.

1. How do I create a converter to change typ to uppercase?
   ---> I solved this question.  The formula below is updated.  :)
2. How do I create a validator to ensure that typ is contained within a list?

I've tried many things on both, but to no avail.  The documentation does not show how to make either a custom converter or validator- or, at least, I do not understand if it does.

```
from attrs import define, field, validators, setters
from datetime import datetime

@define(slots=True)
class Trans:
    acct:   int     = field(validator=validators.instance_of(int), converter=int)
    id:     int     = field(validator=validators.instance_of(int), converter=int)
    ts:     datetime= field(validator=validators.instance_of(datetime))
    typ:    str     = field(converter=(lambda x: x.upper()))

@typ.validator   # this does not work
def typCheck(self, attrib, val):
    if val not in ['A','B','W']:
        raise ValueError('Must be one of these options: ' + str(typs))

a = Trans(1,1,utc,'w')
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For whomever needs it, here is the answer.

```
from attrs import define, field, validators, setters
from datetime import datetime

typs = ['O', 'D', 'W', 'C']

@define(slots=True)
class Trans:
    acct:   int     = field(validator=validators.instance_of(int), converter=int)
    id:     int     = field(validator=validators.instance_of(int), converter=int)
    ts:     datetime= field(validator=validators.instance_of(datetime))
    typ:    str     = field(converter=(lambda x: x.upper()))

    @typ.validator
    def typCheck(self, attrib, val):
        if val not in typs:
            raise ValueError('Must be one of these options: ' + str(typs))

a = Trans(1,1,utc,'w')
a
```

Comment: JFTR, it’s pointless to check the type for int, if you have run the int converter already.  The converter runs before the validator therefore it’s always an int (or explodes if it couldn’t convert it).